# Replace a char with a new line in Python

Tags: python, replace, newline, txt

Im trying to replace in a .txt a charachter with itself and then go to the new line (in this case a '>' with a '> \r\n').
But the .replace function work as expected but the file has the strin '\r\n' instead of going new line.
I feel dumb becouse i dont know what should i do.

```
import fileinput
filename = copyFile
text_to_search = '>'
replacement_text = '>' + '\\r\\n'
with fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace(text_to_search, replacement_text), end='')
```

The input.txt contain :

```
    lorem><ipsum><doloret>impsum
```

After the replace contain :

```
    lorem>\r\n<ipsum>\r\n<doloret>\r\nimpsum
```

And im trying to get :

```
    lorem>
    <ipsum>
    <doloret>
    impsum
```

What im doing wrong?

I tryed:

```
replacement_text = '>' + '\\r\\n'
```

instead of

```
replacement_text = '> \\r\\n'
```

I know that should be the same but one user on StackOverflow managed to make it work like that.
And i tryed to check on internet any other similar problem...

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```py
replacement_text = '>' + '\\r\\n'
```

Should be changed to this:

```py
replacement_text = '>\r\n'
```

`'\\r'` results in a string with the literal backslash (`\`) character followed by an `r`. You want to use `'\r'`, which is the escape sequence for a carriage return.

I also removed the `+` for you since you can just put CRLF in the same string literal after `'>'`.

Answer (score 0):

As @roeen3o already proposed edit. here you can try other ways to achievbe your goal.

```
import re
string = open('a.txt', 'r').read()
string = re.sub(r'^><', '> <', string)
string = string.replace('\\r\\n', '')
print(string)
```

Also Gives #

```
lorem>

<ipsum>

<doloret>

impsum
```